# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, pow, dot-product

I'm trying to do this calculation:

```
import numpy as np

res = (vol).dot(dose[:, np.newaxis]**(1/n))**n
```

where:

```
n = np.linspace(0.01, 0.50, 50)
```

and `vol` is a numpy array with x-number of values ranging from `0.5` to approximately `8000`, and `dose` is a numpy array with x-number of values ranging from `0` to `100`.

If I run it as is I get the `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power`. So it seems to be a problem with the `n` values. Now, if I try to change the `0.01` (lowest value) to `0.02` I have no problems, but it being `0.01` seems to screw something up, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Is there a way to get the program to stop when this Warning is generated, so you can see the circumstances that created it?

Comment: What's the value of `x` you're using?

Comment: maybe you can change ```vol``` and ```dose``` dtype to ```np.float64``` or even ```np.float128``` if it is a precision problem. Try ```vol = vol.astype(np.float128)``` and ```dose = dose.astype(np.float128)```. Then do the calculation again